# Error converting value "9:00 AM" to type 'System.TimeSpan

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

Passing Json data from javascript

```
OpenHours : "9:00 AM"
```

Model property in Server side Web API

```
public TimeSpan OpenHours { get; set; }
```

But getting error as mentioned in the title. 
Using Newtonsoft.Json version 8.0.

Please help to me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"9:00 AM"` is concrete time, not interval.

[Timespan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) is object represents a time interval. You have to use    `TimeSpan.Parse("9:00");`

Comment: I had to parse moment(this.OpenHours , "hh:mm a").format("HH:mm") in javascript. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `TimeSpan` to represent only time of day part, then you can use `TimeSpan.Parse("09:00")`.  Just remove the AM.  For PM, you will need logic to add 12 to the hours, obviously.